# How to take an input while using a command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I want to make a program that permits members by giving them roles for some amount of time

This is my current code

**PLEASE NOTE I HAVE GOT THE SOLUTION THANKS TO @curlybracesenjoyer AND IF YOU ARE LOOKING FOR THE CODE SCROLL DOWN AND SEE THE NEW CODE .....TY**

```py
**OLD CODE**
**FOR NEW CODE PLEASE SEE THE ANSWERS WHERE I HAVE POSTED THE ANSWER MYSELF**
import discord
import os
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

x=0.0#want to use it for float input
y=0.0#want to covert x from hours to seconds

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";")

@bot.command('role')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) #permissions
async def role(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
  if role.position > ctx.author.top_role.position: #if the role is above users top role it sends error
    return await ctx.send('**:x: | That role is above your top role!**') 
  await ctx.channel.send('Enter time in hours')
  #problem 
  #i want to take in x as float input
  #and i want to convert x into seconds and store into y
  await user.add_roles(role) #adds role if not already has it
  await ctx.send(f"Added {role} to {user.mention}") 
  time.sleep()#i want to use y here
  await user.remove_roles(role) #removes the role if user already has
  await ctx.send(f"Removed {role} from {user.mention}") 

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Please copy your code into the question in a code block! Screenshots of code are not fun to look at

Comment: You use `client.wait_for` to get input from a user.  I presume you know the formula for converting hours to seconds.

Comment: @TimRoberts  yes i know the formula but i tried `client.wait_for` but it shows error

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 sry for the inconvenience but the site is messed up when it comes to copy pasting the code so

Comment: It absolutely is not messed up. Secondly, I cannot copy-paste a picture into my editor, I can copy text, even if you don't like the way it looks.

Comment: You'll probably want `bot.wait_for` given you aren't using `client`.

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 yes i added the code snippet 
I tried bot.wait for but it started showing error check=check not assigned

Comment: You haven't included your usage of `wait_for` in your code so I have no idea what the error is. Paste the actual error.

Comment: You'll need to define a `def check(m)` within your command def. Look at the examples here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before moving on the answer, I wanted to mention a few things :

1. We could be using variables attached to `bot` (instance) so we don't have to use `global` which is considered a bad practice
2. We should be using more verbose variable names than `x` and `y`
3. Just having a `sleep` is very bad, because it is blocking the entire functioning of the bot

In asynchronous programming, a blocking call is essentially all the parts of the function that are not await. Do not despair, however, because not all forms of blocking are bad! Using blocking calls is inevitable, but you must work to make sure that you don’t excessively block functions. Remember, if you block for too long then your bot will freeze since it has not stopped the function’s execution at that point to do other things.

A common source of blocking for too long is something like `time.sleep()`. Don’t do that. `Use asyncio.sleep()` instead. Similar to this example:

```py
# bad
time.sleep(10)

# good
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Just waiting for a timing to end is also a bad idea because of how volatile it is, say if you're bot goes offline then the user gets to keep that role forever.
Don't worry too much, you can fix some of those later.

Answer :

To get an floating point number from the same user that has invoked the command, this has to be done :

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    def check(m):
        if m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel:
            try:
                float(m.content)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        return False

    await ctx.send("Tell me the hours")
    res = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    bot.seconds = float(res.content) * 3600
    await ctx.send(f"The seconds are {bot.seconds}")
    # This bot.seconds can be accessed in everywhere
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtBMS.png)

Comment: TYSM!! IT RLY WORKS

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @curlybracketenjoyer who helped in this

to those who are seeing this in the future I resolved my problem and here is my code

```py
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";")

@bot.command()
async def permit(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    def check(m):
        if m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel:
            try:
                float(m.content)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        return False
    permitRole=ctx.guild.get_role(941361821816860732)#the id of particular role you want to give 
    await ctx.send("Tell me the hours")
    res = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    bot.seconds = float(res.content) * 3600
    await user.add_roles(permitRole)#giving the role to mentioned user
    await ctx.send(f"Added role to {user.mention}")#tells the user that the role is given
    await ctx.send(f"The time is {bot.seconds} seconds")#tells the time period of the role to the user
    toime=float(res.content)#gets the message input as float variable
    toimefoinal=toime*3600 #converts to seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(toimefoinal)#sleeps the command 
    await ctx.send("TIME UP")#this is after the time period 
    await user.remove_roles(permitRole)#removes the role 
    await ctx.send("TY FOR CHOOSING THIS SERVER!")

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))#bot token
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMfhR.png)
NOTE: there is no need to fear the role will be taken back after the allotted time this is well tested
again thanks to @curlybracesenjoyer